# How to solve the equation $4x^3+21x^2-18x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$4x^3+21x^2-18x=0$$

Need a step by step because I'm clearly messing up along the way of solving this ! Thanks!

Comment: Are there any roots to the equation you can guess?

Comment: Why don't you start by factoring out an $x$? Do you see that $x=0$ is one solution? Now, do you know how to solve a quadratic equation?

Comment: Step 1: go to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4x%5E3%2B21x%5E2-18x%3D0). Step 2: click "step-by-step solution", it gives you enough to get started even without subscription.

Comment: @NormalHuman, cool. I always used that, Step 3: Type the hint you got in Step 2 and search again, to continue the solution. :P

Answer (score 3):

$x(4x^2+21x-18)=0$

$x(x+6)(4x-3)=0$

Thus, $x=0, -6, 3/4$

Comment: Exactly what Wolfram Alpha shows, and equally helpful.